# BigQuery Challenge: How can we backfill a table with multiple records in Google BigQuery?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

Came across a challenging BigQuery problem and would like to bring all the brightest minds here.
Here's the background, I am trying to match a **membershipID** to the **Table A** below using the **Table B**. It is very easy to map the **membershipID** to the **timestamp 2** and **timestamp 4** back to Table A using left join.
However, I find it quite challenging to backfill the latest **membershipID** back to timestamp 1 and timestamp 3 below.

It is an odd question, so here's some more info:

- One device can log in by multiple membershipID
- Not all events in each timestamp can capture the membershipID, so that's why want to map the membershipID from the latest "login" event (i.e. Table B)

For timestamp 1, we want to map to MemberID_111 (as the session end at timestamp 2)

For timestamp 3, we want to map back MemberID_222 (as the session end at timestamp 4)

**Table A**: The main event table with different timestamps & events, but all of them happened on the same device.

| timestamp | event | device |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | device_A |
| 2 | B | device_A |
| 3 | C | device_A |
| 4 | A | device_A |

**Table B**: Collected the timestamp when the user logged in.

| timestamp | device | membershipID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | device_A | MemberID_111 |
| 4 | device_A | MemberID_222 |

**Output**: The output table we wanted using BigQuery:

| timestamp | event | device | membershipID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | device_A | MemberID_111 |
| 2 | B | device_A | MemberID_111 |
| 3 | C | device_A | MemberID_222 |
| 4 | A | device_A | MemberID_222 |

Hopefully, my question is clear enough above, thanks everyone!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```sql
SELECT * EXCEPT(membershipID),
       FIRST_VALUE(membershipID IGNORE NULLS) OVER w AS membershipID
  FROM tableA LEFT JOIN tableB USING (device, timestamp)
WINDOW w AS (PARTITION BY device ORDER BY timestamp ROWS BETWEEN CURRENT ROW AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING)
 ORDER BY timestamp;

-- or
SELECT * EXCEPT(membershipID),
       LAST_VALUE(membershipID IGNORE NULLS) OVER w AS membershipID
  FROM tableA LEFT JOIN tableB USING (device, timestamp)
WINDOW w AS (PARTITION BY device ORDER BY timestamp DESC)
 ORDER BY timestamp;
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @jaytiger, work as a charm!! Was scratching my head for the whole day and wondering if I have to work this in python instead! Thanks again! Guess I need to understand more on how to use PARTITION here